# How to display recent queries in get method

Tags: php, getmethod

I had this form

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<label>NAME:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
<button>GET</button>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['name'])){

$name = $_GET['name'];

echo "hello".$name;}
?>
```

If entered one name "google"
after that again I entered "example"

is there any way by which I can display recent entered names when I type another?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: Save them in an array in the session: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: i want to display last names entered in the form 

such that showing recent names searched

Comment: Save them in session or in database. Also, `<button>GET</button>` won't send the form. You need to add the `type="submit"` attribute.

Comment: how to save each queries in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code that i think could be enough to handle the issue would be

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET["name"]){
    print "the name parameter was not supplied";
    die();
  }
  session_start();
  $name = $_GET["name"];
  $_SESSION["list"][sizeof($_SESSION["list"])] = $name;
  var_dump($_SESSION["list"]);
  //I used var_dump here only to show the output you are free to use any other
  //way to display the data as you like
```

Comment: that really doesnt matter much just change the POST with the GET and it will get the work done. Wait i will edit the codes up for you

Comment: also here I am getting url at top is

example.com/?name=google
and i want custom url as

example.com/name/google

Comment: @AishwaryaTaneja this should take care of the issue but i must warn you that these changes are not persistant and will be erased once the user closes his browser. If you want the changes to be persistasnt you should consider using a database to store all the entries

Comment: @AishwaryaTaneja for custom routes you should have a look at URL routing  for that you will need to configure your htaccess file in apache and rather than getting from the GET request in PHP get the complete requested URL and parse that to get the request parameter. Here is a script i wrote a little while back that implements url routing also  https://github.com/georoot/finna-ninja/blob/master/index.php

Comment: yes you are right..i must save them in database only

Comment: do you really need the `$_SESSION["list"][sizeof($_SESSION["list"])] = $name;` or could you just do `$_SESSION["list"][] = $name;`?

Comment: @Terminus just a habit i picked up. Yeah $a[] = $name; is also right. Unluckily old habits die hard